# Mysql constant field error occurred when doing related query [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this sql to do query testing :

```
select '1101' as login_id,
a.project_id,a.user_id
from table1 as a on login_id = a.user_id
```

But the error message is:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'on login_id = a.user_id' at line 3

The data in table1 likes this:

| id | project_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | 1002 |
| 2 | A002 | 1001 |
| 3 | A001 | 1001 |
| 4 | A004 | 1003 |
| 5 | A005 | 1004 |

I want the result like this:

| login_id | project_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | null | null |
| 1001 | A002 | 1001 |
| 1001 | A001 | 1001 |
| 1001 | null | null |
| 1001 | null | null |

Our original table3 does not have the `login_id` field. This field is currently replaced by a variable. The variable comes from the parameter passed by java and will be passed to mybatis. In the `mapper.xml` of mybatis, I need to add this column, then use table3 left join table1, the original query result is 50 rows, so I need the result as I said.

How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: You're adding `ON` for non-joins. I think you you just need to change `ON` to `WHERE a.user_id='1101'` and remove `'1101' as login_id` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on` is for table joining, in this case I think you want to do something like this :

```
select '1101' as login_id,
a.project_id,a.user_id
from table1 as a 
where a.user_id = '1101'
```

---

for the expect output you can use `case` :

```
select '1001' as login_id,
case when user_id = '1001' then project_id else null end as project_id,
case when user_id = '1001' then user_id else null end as user_id
from table1
```

here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4da7e0d8098f8b3b355bf2b682d43d55).

just saw the parameter part, just add a parameter which replace `1001` in the syntax and I think the result will be good. although I think keeping all those null data is a weird choose.

Comment: This is very helpful.